# Python Orion Context Broker Token problems

Tags: python-2.7, token, fiware, fiware-orion

I've been developing the following code:

```
    datos = {

            "id":"1",
            "type":"Car",
            "bra":"0",     
    }

    jsonData = json.dumps(datos)
    url = 'http://130.456.456.555:1026/v2/entities'

    head = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Auth-Token": token
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=jsonData, headers=head)
```

My problem is that I can't establish a connection between my computer and my fiware Lab instance.

The error is:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='130.206.113.177', port=1026): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/entities (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f02c97c1f90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a network connectivity problem.

Assuming that there actually an Orion process listening to port 1026 at IP 130.206.113.177 (should be checked, eg. `curl localhost:1026/version` command executed in the same VM where Orion runs), the most probable causes of Orion connection problems are:

- Something in the Orion host (e.g a firewall or security group) is blocking the incoming connection
- Something in the client host (e.g a firewall) is blocking the outcoming connection
- There is some other network issue is causing the connection problem.

Comment: Thanks! The port 1026 was closed!